# Is there a way to query the effect of a possible delete

Tags: mysql, constraints, cascade

Does anyone know if it's possible to query the effect of what a delete WOULD do?

I.E. 
- cannot delete while table X depends on this data
- can delete, and the effect will be that 2 records of table Y, and 5 of table Z will be deleted with it.

Would be a major help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just write the `SELECT ` statement with same `WHERE ` clause, this way you will know the records that will be deleted. Also you can do `COUNT(*)` in your select this way you will know how many records will be affected by it.

Comment: Hi Vladimir. This isn't quite what I had in mind. I hope to find a 'generic' solution. Imagine a user pressing a delete button, and a warning dialogue presents 'are you sure, this, but also every X related pages, Y related files and Z related whatevers will be deleted', or preventing the user to press the delete button at all (whilst explaining the user cannot delete the record because of Y related files preventing the delete (in case of restrict)).

Answer (score 0):

You can find out about "table X depends on this data" concerns by starting a transaction, issuing the `DELETE`, and then rolling the transaction back:

```
START TRANSACTION;
<your query here>;
```

See what kind of feedback you get, then roll it back:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

Or if you like what you see, just `COMMIT`.

Comment: Hi Ed. I also thought of this solution, but the problem with this one is the lack of details about the related records.